# Generics in low level languages

Tags: design, object-oriented, c, generics

I'm developing a language like [Vala](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala) and [OOC](http://ooc-lang.org) that compiles back to C.

This means that, eventually, every feature needs to be adoptable to C code in some way or another. Generics is one of the features I'd like to implement in my language.

As you probably know, C is a strictly typed language. Except for the opaque void pointer, there is no way to pass an argument of a unknown type. This is because the compiler needs to know the exact size of the argument passed or returned.

The following solutions come to my mind:

1. Boxing: Create a union that can store every possible type
2. Pass a pointer to the parameter, rather than the parameter itself.

Both of these have their downsides:

1. - The size of the generic type `T` will be equal to the largest possible type
   - The sizes are predetermined, a struct with a different size cannot be passed by value
   - Slower, because every argument has to be boxed/unboxed
2. - The parameter is not copied onto the new stack scope
   - Memory management issues because of the above
   - Not the desired behaviour because of the above

I'm interested in knowing how I could adopt this high-level principle in a lower level language, and also how other high-level languages have conquered this problem.

*EDIT*

As @delnan has pointed out, another possibility is Monomorphization, creating a new function for every data type. This has a few of the same downsides:

- The type `T` needs to be defined beforehand (not very generic)
- The binary size gets larger (which, granted, isn't very relevant nowadays)

Comment: As an inspiration, have a look at Ada implementations. Ada can produce low-level code and has quite capable generics. Second, note that compiling to C from another language might complicate static type checking (you will probably have to know how C deals with types in your language).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Monomorphization. For every generic (polymorphic) type/function, generate a non-generic (monomorphic) version for every set of type parameters. Given these declarations:

```
struct G<T> {
  a: T,
  b: T
}

fn get_a<T>(g: G<T>) -> T {
  return g.a;
}
```

and this code:

```
x = G<int>(1, 2);
y = G<float>(1.0, 2.0);
get_a(x);
get_a(y);
```

Generate code equivalent to:

```
struct G_int {
  a: int,
  b: int
}

struct G_float {
  a: float,
  b: float
}

fn get_a_int(g: G_int) -> int {
  return g.a;
}

fn get_a_float(g: G_float) -> float {
  return g.a;
}

x = G_int(1, 2);
y = G_float(1.0, 2.0);
get_a_int(x);
get_a_float(y);
```

This also works across library barriers! It requires the code (at least in AST/IR form) of generics to be included with library binaries, but aside from that the compiler can simply generate the code in the same way, just taking the "template" from a different source. Duplicate definitions (when two libraries instantiate the same generic with the same type parameters) can be merged by the linker and at worst increase compile time.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about this one. This is how C++ does it. That one has a few of the same downsides though: Every type has to be predefined. In a library e.g. you can't know what types the user of your library is going to use.

Comment: @NSAddict Not at all, see my edit.

Comment: Wait until you get the dreaded "Monomorphism Restriction" from the compiler because of type ambiguity...

Comment: @recursion.ninja The monomorphism restriction is a Haskell thing (in particular, a typeclass thing), only applies to top-level bindings without any parameters, and is not technically necessary (it can be turned off with the only consequence being possibly-slower code). Did you perhaps mean something else?

Comment: @delnan It was meant as a joke; a reference to how Haskell implements generics through type-classes.

Answer (score 5):

currently there are 2 ways;

1. the type erasure method of java; essentially everything becomes a void* (or a custom type like a `struct base{void** functptrs;}` and gets casted to and fro as needed, this requires the type to follow a certain interface to let the template figure out if casts are valid at runtime.
2. instantiation creates a new definition of the template like delnan explained; this is what is used in C++. It does cause some code bloat as you need to let the client recompile the template each time it is used.

Comment: C# does both ( type erasure for classes, instantiation for value types) so it's not a binary choice.

Comment: @PeteKirkham C# doesn't use type erasure. Type information is persisted in run time.

Comment: @KonradMorawski the specialisation is preserved in the reflected type information, but for generating code the behaviour is to erase the type - *The first time a generic type is constructed with any reference type, the runtime creates a specialized generic type with object references substituted for the parameters in the MSIL. Then, every time that a constructed type is instantiated with a reference type as its parameter, regardless of what type it is, the runtime reuses the previously created specialized version ...* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4a6ta2h.aspx

Comment: @PeteKirkham maybe it's my English, but to me it doesn't mean that type information is erased at all. *Specialized generic type* is created, and then it is *reused*. How could `Stack<int>` be ever reused if the `<int>` bit wasn't preserved? I'm tempted to post this as a question.